# Why do I get two different looking SaveAs Overwrite prompts?

Tags: c#, excel

I have two different Excel files and do some changes with both. When I SaveAs… each file gets prompted to confirm an existing file and the option to overwrite it. I am aware that I can avoid this altogether with a Save() command instead, but I am trying to understand why are there two different looking overwrite prompts?

Everything is saved properly and no errors occur.

In my C# code I am using version MS Excel 14.0 Object Library.  (Excel 2010)
The IDE I am using is MS Visual Studio 2015 Community.
Operating system is Win 7 x64. Hardware flavor AMD.

Thank you for your time.

SaveAs Dialog 1:

[image]

SaveAs dialog 2

[image: SaveAs Dialog 2]

The code I used to test this...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace SO_Question
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
        EditSaveExcelFiles();
      }

      public static void EditSaveExcelFiles()
      {
         object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
         string file1 = @"C:\Users\John\Documents\New Folder\MyExcel.xlsx";
         string file2 = @"C:\Users\John\Documents\New Folder\MyExcel2.xlsx";
         Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
         Workbook workBook1 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(file1, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
         Workbook workBook2 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(file2, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
         Worksheet workSheet1 = (Worksheet)workBook1.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
         Worksheet workSheet2 = (Worksheet)workBook2.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");

         // do some stuff
         workSheet1.Cells[1, 1] = "Grazer14";
         workSheet2.Cells[1, 1] = "Grazer24";

         // Different overwrite dialogs?
         try
         {
           workBook1.SaveAs(file1, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
           workBook2.SaveAs(file2, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
           //when user clicks "No" or "Cancel"
           //MessageBox.Show("No or Cancel: " + e.StackTrace);
         }
         workBook2.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
         workBook1.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
         ExcelApp.Quit();
         System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook1);
         System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook2);
         System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How can it be that the first screenshot is missing the "New Folder" in path? are you sure that screenshot was taken using the code you posted?

Comment: The only difference is the file format you are saving with - it must be that that's causing the difference. What do you get if you try different SaveAs options interactively?

Comment: @dlatikay yes that was an earlier picture. Updated now Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisF I have not really tried to change many of the options in the SaveAs parameters because it did not look like any of them had any thing to do with this. Any suggestions. I can easily change an option and test it. I will admit I have not tried much in that area.

Comment: @Chris I did not see that the files were different types. I updated the question with the same types. Even with this change I get two different dialogs.

Comment: @JohnG - Oh. That blows my theory out of the water then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see here is that the first message box displayed by Excel is not themed, whereas the second one is. It's got nothing to do with the particular files that you are saving (in fact, you can save the same file twice and still see the same behavior).

The fix is to make the Excel application visible before saving:

```
excelApp.Visible = true;
```

That way, the Excel UI will be properly initialized. You simply can't expect an invisible app to have its UI initialized correctly — Excel is designed to either work with its full UI or with no UI at all.

If you want to avoid the prompt and automatically overwrite an existing file, you have to disable display alerts:

```
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
workBook1.SaveAs(file1);
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

Comment: I was trying to help someone with a different problem and my solution involved this situation. I kept getting the two dialogs. So I felt there may be something I was missing so I didn’t submit the solution. And it has been a head scratcher for me ever since. But you are 100% correct. It also makes sense from the way you described _Excel is designed to either work with its full UI or with no UI at all._ it never occurred to me to simply make the app visible to solve this conundrum.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough and I am sorry that the issue was not that earth shattering but your explanation is spot on and it makes sense. Thank you very much ;-)